# nodejs, github, npm, and symbolic links

Tags: git, node.js, github, npm

i have a nodejs project with a few dependencies on my own modules. as per npm's current best practices, those dependencies are represented using the `npm link`/`npm link $package-name` commands, so the project now has some symbolic links in its `node_modules`. locally that works.

however when i push that project to github, the links are preserved as links, meaning that other people that clone it will (very likely) see broken links. another point is that i push the `node_modules` directory to github at all—that's ok in so far cloning from github now gives you a complete instance of the project with all dependencies resolved, but on the other hand i suddenly have a lot of 3rd party stuff in my repo.

what is the best practice to deal with this kind of situation?

**edit** one thing i just realized is that checking in dependencies as installed code is wrong anyhow—there might be some binaries involved that need to get installed in a platform-specific way. so you never check in your dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not include the `node_modules` directory in your source repository. Git is for **source code**, not built distributions. That is the best practice as it has been for decades. Ignore the hipsters you see occasionally putting build artifacts into git. They are wrong, they just haven't felt the pain enough yet to realize it. Besides just being incorrect from a sound methodology perspective, including your node_modules in git will fail when (not if) your project includes any extensions with C components that are compiled per-platform. This will fail requiring at least an `npm rebuild` by the user who cloned the repo to fix it, and at that point you might as well just have them do the `npm install` as `$Deity` intended.

Answer (score 2):

First, do not include other node modules in your git project

```bash
cd ~/your_module && echo "/node_modules" >> .gitignore
```

Second, if your module has dependencies, just declare them in your `package.json`. Here's an example from my [burro](https://github.com/naomik/burro/blob/master/package.json#L24-L30) module

```
// package.json
{
  // ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "~1.8.1",
    "hiccup": "~0.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bun": "~0.0.5"
  }
}
```

For what it's worth, I do not actually use the `npm link` feature; I build/test all of my modules separately. There's a good handful of them you can see on my github [repositories](https://github.com/naomik?tab=repositories) if you want other examples.

My basic workflow is this:

1. patch module A
2. bump version on module A
3. `npm publish` module A
4. bump version dependency of module A in module B
5. re-`npm install` module A in module B
6. patch module B to work with new version of module A (if required)
7. bump version on module B
8. `npm publish` module B

`npm link` is handy, but I think it enables/encourages too tight of a coupling between your modules. I firmly believe the "do one thing and do it well" mantra and keep this in mind when authoring all of my modules. Using this workflow will help keep your functionality well-encapsulated and the community will love your releases.

---

As for the github bit, `npm` doesn't really care about this. As a habit, before I `npm publish` a release, I will always tag that commit with the module version. Here's an example

1. set version to "0.1.5" in `package.json`
2. `git commit -m "bump to version 0.1.5"`
3. `git tag v0.1.5`
4. `git push origin master --tags`
5. `npm publish`

Now both npmjs.org and github.com both agree on the same version. Users downloading your package from either source will always get the same thing.

Comment: So if you're working on a feature that requires you to change both module A and module B, you'll do the "patch / bump / publish / etc.." dance basically every time you edit a file in A, right ? How do you manage to avoid that ?

Comment: @phtrivier you can't avoid it; and shouldn't. The modules are separate and should be versioned accordingly. The point of modularizing things in the first place is so that each lib can grow independently as the requirements for that lib change.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The problem is that I use a module mainly to share code, not so much to split or organize logically. I've been advised elsewhere to split / refactor / reorganise, but the only outcome I can foresee is *more* complexity and work for my teamates whenever they want to make even the most trivial change. So I'll admit I am a little paralysed :/